# Laravel eagerly loading multiple models that are all in the same table

Tags: laravel, eloquent

For an example
Let's say we have an **users** table and a **posts** table.

Users table has **id** and **name** columns.

Posts table has **creator_id** and **approved_by_id** that both exist (reference) in users table.
How can I eagerly load this with one query?

```
select * from posts where id in (z)
select * from users where id in (x,y) //(creator, approver)
```

at the moment I have these relations:

```
public function created_by()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'creator_id');
}

public function approved_by()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'approved_by_id');
}
```

Comment: Eager loading never uses a single query. One to get the model, one for each relationship.

Comment: If i select multiple rows it uses **where id in (1,2,3,4)** = one query.
I can't achieve it with multiple relations from the same table?

Comment: If you do `Post::with(['created_by', 'approved_by'])->get();` it will do `select * from posts` followed by `select * from users where id in (xx)` and `select * from users where id in (yy)` where xx and yy are the values of `creator_id` and `approved_by_id` columns of all the original records. These columns are all indexed and performance should not be a concern.

Comment: Performance is not an issue. I just dislike seeing same queries being run (if creator and approver are the same for an example).

Comment: You don't see it, unless you're sitting there monitoring your database query log.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guarantee you are not running a dataset big enough for performance of eager loading to be a concern. But, if having multiple queries bothers you and you'd rather incur the technical debt of managing a query builder command, I think this should work:

```php
$post = Post::select('posts.*')
    ->selectRaw('creator.name as creator_name')
    ->selectRaw('approver.name as approver_name')
    ->leftJoin('users as creator', 'posts.creator_id', 'creator.id')
    ->leftJoin('users as approver', 'posts.approved_by_id', 'approver.id')
    ->where('posts.id', $post_id)
    ->get();
```

We just join the users table twice with different aliases; to avoid overwriting the column values they need to be aliased as well. Your data will be a different format of course, you won't have access to things like `$post->created_by->name` but will instead rely on the column aliases.

The equivalent SQL query would be:

```sql
SELECT posts.*, creator.name AS creator_name, approver.name AS approver_name
FROM posts
LEFT JOIN users AS creator ON (posts.creator_id = creator.id)
LEFT JOIN users AS approver ON (posts.approved_by_id = approver.id)
WHERE posts.id = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly

```
User::with(['created_by', 'approved_by'])
   ->get()
```

Comment: This creates two (extra) queries.

Comment: Then only an arbitrary query with a left join

Comment: What's that? Can you provide an example?

Comment: SELEC u.*, s.`name` FROM `users` as u LEFT JOIN `users` as c ON u.`creator_id` = s.`id`